# Create array of integers and have a function check each value

Tags: jquery, arrays, integer

Trying to achieve something that I'm not sure is possible. I am trying to create a custom function for our ecommerce site that uses a plugin for Wordpress. The idea is create a sort of conditional logic based on the choice of wood a customer chooses. The kicker is if for some reason the original choice has the options re-arrange the value of the radio button changes.

This is what I currently have and at the moment it does work for the current set up:

```
$('input:radio[name="tmcp_radio_0"]').on('change',function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'Oak_0') {
        $(".oak-stains-div").show();
            $oakchecked.prop('checked', false);
            $oakactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
    } else {
        $(".oak-stains-div").hide();
    }
});
```

I'm trying to make it work in any situation though. My goal is to have it check the value. For example right now it is checking if the value of the radio button is "Oak_0" and then shows the proper stains for that wood. If for some reason the Oak option moved on the backend, now on the front end it could read "Oak_1".

Is there a way to create a integer variable so it checks a range of values? Like if I set an integer range of "1-9" it would check the values for "Oak_*" or "Oak_1", "Oak_2", etc. Trying to cut the fat and make it to where I am not typing it all out for it to check. I am not sure if creating an array and then having it check through that array would work best.

I'm not the best with Jquery so any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Side note; the usage of `:checked` is intended to be used as a selector.  In the situation of `$(this).is(':checked')` the use of the pseudo-selector is unnecessary overhead as `this.checked` will return the same result.

Comment: @Taplar thanks for pointing that out. Was working off an old snippet I had and forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regex to check whether the option started with `Oak` and finished with a `_` and some digits:

```
if ($(this).is(':checked') && /^Oak_\d+$/.test($(this).val())) {
```

This will match anything from `Oak_0` upwards (`Oak_1`, `Oak_2`, ...). If you want to restrict it to e.g. `Oak_9` as a maximum, replace `\d+` with `\d`.

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Put it on our staging site and worked right away. Thank you very much!